# Wifi only works after reboot - how to comepltely reset wifi?

Tags: networking, wireless, 19.10

Wifi occasionally doesn't work after wake from sleep (Ubuntu 19.10, Lenovo Yoga). It works if I reboot. So it must be a software problem. How do I completely reset wifi?

I'm doing this at the moment:

```
sudo ifconfig wlp2s0 down;
sudo /sbin/modprobe -r ath10k_pci
sudo /sbin/modprobe ath10k_pci
sudo dpkg-reconfigure resolvconf
sudo service network-manager restart
```

However, it's somehow not the same as a restart. What else can I try?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had issues also.  Now I love Wicd Network Manger.  I will have nothing available through the wifi settings in Ubuntu and Wicd sees my connections, lets me choose and connects while Ubuntu's Wifi still shows a 802.1x error. also try this cmd, worked well for me
maybe **sudo** in front: **systemctl start NetworkManager** I thought for a while it was my intel 8260. Could be driver problem with Ubuntu?  Hope it helps you, did me.

Comment: Thank you very much for taking the time to write. I've added this to my 'fix wifi' script, and will see what it does next time wifi fails!

Comment: Amazing! Installing wicd seems to do the trick. Same observation as you: Nothing available in the Ubuntu Wifi settings, but wicd is able to see networks and connected. This is sooooo helpful. Many thanks!

Comment: I'm 48 with brain damage from a car crash 3 years ago.  Alwayys  have loved computers.  Thought I was doing something wrong about my connections.  Wicd helped me, thought I would share in case someone else could benefit, I'm so glad you did! Best to you my friend!! **bjohas: Help me?  Can't  change DE from log screen.  no cog to click choice anymore. no gui, if I change auto login to off.  Words of wisdom from you bjohas ? Thank you for your time, wishing I would have stayed with 18.04, but I will stay strong

Comment: What do you mean by DE? Language? I have a language selector at the top right.

Comment: bjohas, Sorry I was in Ubuntu Wayland Desktop Enviroment DE, and when I rebooted black screen! I was almost at my normal desktop.  STUCK,Did  something like the ctrl-alt-f2, saw my login there.  I finally got in by typing startx and that opened the desktop back up.  Changed my login from settings back to auto-login and all is good, unless I try to logout.  Basically the choices I had before for different DE were,,,,Unbuntu/Ubuntu Wayland/gnome classic, and something else.  I can't get back to regular Ubuntu.  Looking for a way to reload that enviroment?  I'm guessing some command does it

Comment: Ah, I see. So you want to switch back from Wayland to Gnome?

Comment: Yeah, I like switching back in forth.  Just found something out!!!  copy and paste: Bugs in package gdm3 (version 3.34.1-1) in unstable This could be why I have NO login options when I logout.  Possibly the other enviroments dont like gdm vs gdm3 enviroment!  Looking in to it as we speak.  I was out of my login for 3 hours today. GRRRRR

Comment: Ah I see - let me know what you find!